# Office JS Excel Disabling button after click

Tags: office-js

I'm working on an Excel add-in using the JavaScript APIs to build add-ins in Excel Office 365.  Using the manifest,I created a ribbon which as 4 buttons. On click of each button, a worksheet is opened with some Table content.

I want to disable the buttons in the excel ribbon once they are clicked & the tables are rendered. i.e. once the javascript function tied to the Excel ribbon button is done with its task. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Curious, when/how would you expect the buttons to be re-enabled?  I get that you want to disable them after the user performs an operation, but when will they be enabled again?  If you can share your scenario in more detail that would help us design a feature in the future to meet your needs. Thanks

Comment: This is required more from a  workflow perspective. If a workflow has 10 steps based on 10 sequential user action.  Action 1 - disables the button. User goes ahead and does action 2 , 3 ....till 9. Once Action 10 is completed, the button should be active for user to perform action meant for that user.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Having a bunch of buttons on the Ribbon to depict "Steps" seems a bit strange to me, even if we supported it from a platform perspective I wouldn't recommend it ux-wise.  Perhaps a single "Actions" or "Workflow" button that then shows a pane with the next-previous step would be better?  You could even provide a nicer visualization of the flow that way.  Thoughts?

Comment: Lets assume there are 2 buttons only. The buttons need to be active / inactive based on roles. If a person has sufficient privileges , then both the button should be active. If insufficient privilege, then the corresponding button needs to be inactive.

Comment: Got it- so is more like role-based UI. Makes sense. Will keep into account

Answer (score 2):

Buttons within the ribbon can not be enabled/disabled programmatically at this time. There is a [request in UserVoice for this](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/6509264-client-side-ribbon-manipulation) that is currently under review. As always, your votes of support would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As I type this, UserVoice is DOWN. Sigh... And it's been four years since you answered. This seems like critical functionality: I can't have buttons in Word bring up the taskpane, and I can't have them disabled when the taskpane is disabled.